# How to apply a fixed background in fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I am not asking how to make a background image, I know how to do that. I am asking how to apply a fixed background which stays the same throughout the site without moving. Scrolling up/down will move through the slides content.
My current code sets the background image to the first slide and the subsequent slides are white.

This is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section" id="section0" data-anchor="thisSection0">
        <h1>Section0</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="section" id="section1" data-anchor="thisSection1">
        <h1>Section1</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="section" id="section2" data-anchor="thisSection2">
        <h1>Section2</h1>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#fullpage {
background-image: url('images/bg1.jpg');
}
```

SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#fullpage").fullpage({
         anchors: ['thisSection0', 'thisSection1', 'thisSection2'],
         responsive: 900,
         navigation: true,
         navigationPosition: 'right',
         navigationTooltips: ['Section 0', 'Section 1', 'Section 2']
     });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

background-attachment is the key. Use

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Also based on your requirement you will need to play around with background- `background-repeat:no-repeat;` and `background-size:contain/cover;` so that the background image looks as you want

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/cipenuxero/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: I have tried using this on #fullpage and it does not work. I think it might be somethimg to do with the framework. Any other ideas??

Comment: @user3589485 its got nothing to do with framework. Its a common css property.

Comment: @user3589485 i ve added a jsbin, check that

Comment: I managed to solve this with your help but I had to set css3:false in the framework script page and add:

background-image: url('images/bg1.jpg');
background-attachment: fixed;

to #fullpage AND every #section1, #section2, #section3 in the css.

thanks

Comment: I would also point to [this issue](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/208) related with a bug in Chrome when using `css3:true` in fullPage.js.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css property fixed for the background attachment:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#fullpage {
    background-image: url('images/bg1.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```